# Why the children combinator > selects grandchildren in some cases?

Tags: html, css, dom, children

According to the theory, the css children combinator element1 > element2:

> "it matches only those elements matched by the second selector
> that are the DIRECT children of elements matched by the first."

However, in the following code example, which is a variation of the code provided in the [mozilla reference children combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) it would select the grandchild `<p>` as well.
The original example it works with `<span>` element and doesnt select the grandchild p #2.
However,if we replace `<span>` with `<p>` (or any other element tag like h1,article,a etc) as in the code below, p#2 grandchild is selected.
Am I missing something?

```
enter code here
<style>  
  p {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  div > p {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<div>
    <p>p #1, is child of the div.
      <p>p #2, is grandchild of the div.</p> <!--why p #2 is selected?--> 
    </p>
</div>
<p>p #3, is not in the div at all.</p>
```

Comment: Probably because the HTML is invalid. You can't nest paragraphs.